# R: Perform a partial match in column B based on unique values from column A

Tags: r

I have a table of suppliers that contain a local supplier ID, local supplier name, a source system and a global supplier ID and global supplier name. We have previously created this table to essentially assign the "same" supplier from different systems to the same global supplier ID for analytical purposes.

Since we created this mapping, we have received a few more thousand suppliers for additional systems that we need to create mappings for. Instead of doing so by hand, I'd like to work with a script to create most matches automatically. My approach is as follows:

1. Identify all unique values of "global supplier name" and "global supplier ID" and assign this to "uniqueGlobalSupplier".
2. Loop over "uniqueGlobalSupplier". For each entry, look in the column for "local supplier name" and see if the value of "global supplier name" is found. If so, add "global supplier ID" from my loop to the line where that partial match occurred.

I was thinking of a code somewhere along these lines ...

```
for (row in unique(df1$`Text/Beschreibung`)) {
  # find partial match of value of 'row' in column 'local supplier name' and perform update logic if found.
}
```

However, I only of the description here and not the global supplier ID and I don't know how to perform that partial match in column 'local supplier name'. Any help is **much** appreciated!

Sample data as follows:

[image: Sample data]

Here I want to essentially find "3M" as the unique global supplier name and add its global supplier ID to all entries that contain "3M" in their local supplier name.

Comment: Hey could you provide some data?

Comment: I added some sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this? I use apply instead of your for loop and test if the name exists with `grep`. And if it exists the *globalSupplierID* is set. The test `is.na(df2$globalSupplierID)` prevent that already given *globalSupplierID* are overwritten.

```
df1 <- data.frame(globalSupplierName=c("A","B","C","D"), globalSupplierID=1:4)
df2 <- data.frame(localSupplierName=c("A xy","B xy","A yx","D yx"), globalSupplierID=NA)

apply(df1, 1, function(x) {
  df2$globalSupplierID[grepl(x["globalSupplierName"], df2$localSupplierName) & is.na(df2$globalSupplierID)]  <<- x["globalSupplierID"]
})
df2
#  localSupplierName globalSupplierID
#1              A xy                1
#2              B xy                2
#3              A yx                1
#4              D yx                4
```